# Obter todas conexões relacionadas a um IP

Tags: .net, vb.net, ip

É possível obter todos os ips que estão conectados a um IP em Visual Basic? Por exemplo, eu pegar o IP de todos jogadores que estiverem conectados à um servidor de um jogo. Tentei a variável `System.NET.IPHostEntry.Aliases` porém não retornou nada...

Comment: Acho que só tendo acesso ao servidor do jogo

Comment: Não creio nisso

Comment: Você pode não crêr, a verdade pode doer, mas pegar estas informações da maneira q está/entendi em sua pergunta é impossível.

Comment: O que pode ser feito é sniffar o gateway de sua rede e pegar os ips que estão fechando conexão com o ip do servidor do jogo o que é "impossível"  de se conseguir usando qq aplicação de uma máquina segmentada de sua rede, existem métodos para envenenar a rede e redirecionar o tráfego para uma máquina da rede e nesta maquina se fazer uso de sniffer, isso não tem nada haver em usar vb, a não ser que você desenvolva o sniffer em vb.

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta descreve uma arquitetura [Cliente-servidor](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliente-servidor), ou seja cada cliente(IP) se conecta ao IP do servidor, neste tipo de comunicação somente o servidor possui a informação dos clients conectados a ele, fazendo uma analogia imagine que uma atendente de telemarketing faça três ligações simultâneas, uma destas ligações foi destinado a você, como você vai saber o nome das outras duas pessoas? como você saberia que existe outras duas pessoas falando ou em espera com a telefonista ? Ou você pergunta para a telefonista com quantas pessoas ela está falando e qual o nome dos usuários em linha ou você tem acesso a central telefônica, o mesmo acontece em uma arquitetura Cliente-servidor.

A utilização de Sniffer pode informar quais IPs de sua rede interna estão se conectando com o servidor, não vai ser possível pegar quais IPs ao redor do mundo estão conectados, se você tiver acesso a rede do servidor do jogo é outra historia mas entendi não ser o caso. O fato é que não existem meios de conhecer quais clientes estão conectados diretamente a um servidor sem você ter acesso a ele (não estamos falando aqui de possíveis furos de segurança no servidor na qual talvez possa dar brechas para conseguir estas informações de forma ilegal).

Se você tiver acesso ao servidor um simples `netstat -na` vai listar todos os IPs conectados diretamente a ele.

Comment: Posso obter o `netstat -na` para um outro ip público?

Comment: Não, imagine só se isso fosse possível eu poderia pegar todos os IPs que estão conectados agora no webserver do StackOverflow, isso seria um furo de segurança mt grande, como te disse o que você quer e da maneira que você quer não é possível ...

Comment: Entendi, obrigado